# Form field textarea count

Tags: javascript, forms

I found the following JavaScript that counts down the characters in a textarea and displays it in another textbox. It's perfect for what I need except it uses the field name. My fields are arrays (`short_descripton[]` and `long_description[]`). Is there a way to use the field id instead of the name?

```
<script>
function textCounter(field,cntfield,maxlimit) {
if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
// otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
else
cntfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
}
</script>
```

Here's a field example:

```
<textarea id=sd1 rows="2" name="short_description[]">
onKeyDown="textCounter(document.myForm.short_description[],document.myForm.remLen1,125)"
onKeyUp="textCounter(document.myForm.short_description[],document.myForm.remLen1,125)">
</textarea>
<br>
<input readonly type="text" name="remLen1" size="3" maxlength="3" value="125">
characters left
```

As always, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in a call to document.getElementById() with the id you want.

`onKeyDown="textCounter(document.getElementById('sd1'),document.myForm.remLen1,125)"
onKeyUp="textCounter(document.getElementById('sd1'),document.myForm.remLen1,125)">`

Comment: Thanks, Jrod. I changed my Javascript code a little and it worked.

    function textCounter(field,cntfield,maxlimit) {
    var total = field.length;
    //alert(cntfield);
    if (total > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
    total = total.substring(0, maxlimit);
    // otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
    else
    cntfield.value = maxlimit - total;
    //alert(cntfield.value);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can ! Take a look:

```
<textarea id=sd1 rows="2" name="short_description[]"
onKeyDown="textCounter(this,document.getElementById('remLen1'),125)"
onKeyUp="textCounter(this,document.getElementById('remLen1'),125)">
</textarea>
<br>
<input readonly type="text" name="remLen1" id="remLen1" size="3" maxlength="3" value="125">
characters left
```

1. In that scope you can use **this** instruction to send reference of the object.
2. Always try to use the ID of the object instead of *document.myForm.remLen1* cause isn't a cross-browser method and I'm afraid that just works on Internet Explorer.
3. Remeber to validate the length of the content in server-size. This method can be avoid by experienced users.